# Regular Expression which would allow only positive integer number from 20 and above

Tags: regex

Trying for a Regex that would allow positive integers from 20 and above upto 1000 or 10000. 0 to 19 should be allowed and also no decimal, negative and alphabets should be allowed.

I'm trying with this but not getting it.

```
r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])"
```

[Update] Don't want to include number from 0 to 19.

Comment: "allow numbers from 20 - 1000". "also allow 0 - 19". Huh?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'm guessing OP meant to write "0 to 19 should *not* be allowed", since he then goes on to list 3 other things that "also" shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I agree that would seem logical (specially with the title), however I wish OP would've clarified. I'm not trying to point fingers at someone making a typo/not being a native speaker, but instead making sure that OP realizes there might be a mistake in the post (that could change the answers of others, hence the reason no one has edited).

Comment: Sorry everyone for the confusion. I will add some more info so that it is clear. Thanks @p.s.w.g for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,}
```

This will match a two-digit number greater than or equal to 20, or a number with three or more digits. Depending on exactly how you're using it, you may need to place start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around the pattern to prohibit any extra characters in the input:

```
^([2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})$
```

If you want to limit this to numbers up to 1000:

```
^([2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|1000)$
```

If you want to limit this to numbers up to 10000:

```
^([2-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,3}|10000)$
```

Comment: this will match numbers greater than 1000 though

Comment: @RyanSaxe I assume OP just meant to imply that it should match arbitrarily large numbers, but it's a good point. I've included alternatives for those situations as well.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks a lot for the additional options.